# How do you Split Action strips?

Tags: animation

I have a group of keyframes that dashes then jumps 
I want to separate these into two different actions and manage them separately.

So how do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will include an excerpt from https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WrrdFpZ-VC7taxu4iD3hZIowYvyM953iZpBwkZ78PgA/edit :

**splitting actions**

This is probably the most difficult of the workflows.  When you are starting out with NLAs and haven't made a habit of creating small reusable chunks you will often realize "I wish I had split this up before now."

The essence of splitting is to create a copy and delete part from each.  Let's refer to those two parts as A and B.

Make a backup of your .blend file first, just to be safe.

Imagine your action is currently the primary action.  Use the Dope Sheet/Action Editor to give it a "good" name (maybe "AplusB").  Then use the chevron to move it into an action strip.  Create a new track and create a new action strip in that new track that refers to the same action.   You now have two action strips referring to the same action datablock.  Go ahead and create a third action strip referring to the same action datablock as a sort of information bunker in case you make a mistake later on.

Make one of the strips active and hit the Tab key to start editing it.  Use the Dope Sheet/Action Editor to make a single-user copy of the action (click the [3] button).  Now give it a name that identifies which half of the action it will become (maybe "part B").  After that, you can delete all the keyframes that don't belong in the action (delete the A, leave the B).  Memorize the name of the new action.  Hit Tab to stop editing that action strip.  Now change the Action of the action strip to refer to the new action.

Make the other strip active and hit the Tab key to start editing it.  Use the Dope Sheet/Action Editor to make another single-user copy copy of the datablock (click the [2] button).  You can rename it (maybe "part A").  You can now use the Graph Editor to remove all the B keyframes and leave the A keyframes.  Don't forget to point the strip at the new action.

Before you test the animation you should discard the 3rd (information bunker) action strip but not before you click the [f] button next to the action name in the Dope Sheet/Action Editor to give it a Fake user so blender will not garbage-collect the AplusB action.  That way you can still recover it later if you find problems with the animation.

Answer (score 5):

If the Action strips are NLA-enabled:

1. Select the action in the NLA.
2. From the NLA menu, select `Edit` ->> `Split Strips` (Y is the default shortcut).

If they aren't NLA-enabled:

1. In the Action Editor, create a new action by clicking the '+' symbol next to the action to duplicate the action.

[image: Duplicate an action]

2. Select the newly duplicated action, and edit out the keyframes from the first part of the action, and label it whatever the later action is called (ie) 'Jump').